# Large amount of Espresso tests running with coverage is getting stuck after tests run

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, android-espresso, spoon

Espresso tests with coverage stuck after running all the tests.  I have to force stop the app manually to finish the task. The task gets finished only when I manually force stop the app.   I don't see this issue if I run few tests.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Here is what I see in logcat, output:

**In logcat**:

> 1-25 10:00:08.938 27943-27969/com.test.debug I/TestRunner: run finished: 278 tests, 71 failed, 0 ignored
>   01-25 10:00:11.285 27943-27962/com.test.debug I/BranchSDK: returned {}
>   01-25 10:00:31.830 27943-27969/com.test.debug I/MonitoringInstr: waitForActivitiesToComplete() took: 0ms
>   01-25 10:00:31.831 1588-2135/system_process W/WindowManager: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@9cd6d9a
>   01-25 10:00:31.834 27943-27943/com.test.debugI/MonitoringInstr: Activities that are still in CREATED to STOPPED: 0
>   01-25 10:00:31.839 27943-27969/com.test.debug E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 4574692)
>   01-25 10:00:59.559 1225-1286/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 3308 syncs in 60s
>   01-25 10:01:59.550 1225-1286/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 3306 syncs in 60s
>   01-25 10:02:01.539 1916-32035/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
>   01-25 10:02:59.555 1225-1286/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 3309 syncs in 60s
>   01-25 10:03:59.556 1225-1286/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 3310 syncs in 60s

**In output I am seeing this over and over:**

> 10:02:45.600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon]   DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
>   10:02:45.601 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
>   10:02:45.601 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
>   10:02:45.601 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
>   10:02:45.602 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
>   10:02:45.602 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
>   10:02:45.602 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
>   10:02:47.109 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 4601053184}
>   10:02:47.109 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 4601053184}
>   10:02:47.109 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 5726797824, Committed: 4952948736}
>   10:02:52.108 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 4597641216}
>   10:02:52.108 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 4597641216}

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?